# generating KML file using C# and LINQ with a recursive function

Tags: c#, xml, kml

I am trying to create a KML file dynamically in C#. I have wrote a recursive function to do this. However the result of output has a bit problem. The problem is the position of closing tags of all placemarks. I am really confused. Please tell me where am I making mistake in the recursive function???

My code:

```
private void xmlBuild()
    {
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
        new XComment("This is comment by me"),
        new XElement(ns+"kml", 
        new XElement(ns+"Document", rec_build())));      
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\markers2.xml"));
}
private XElement rec_build()
    {
        if (iteration != 0)
        {
            iteration -= 1;
            return final_rec = new XElement(ns + "Placemark",
                    new XAttribute("id", "1"),
                    new XElement(ns + "title", "something"),
                    new XElement(ns + "description", "something"),
                    new XElement(ns + "LookAt",
                    new XElement(ns + "Longitude", "49.69"),
                    new XElement(ns + "Latitude", "32.345")), new XElement(ns + "Point", new XElement(ns + "coordinates", "49.69,32.345,0")),rec_build());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and this is the output for iteration value of 2: (please notice the closing tags of placemark id=1 at the end of file. It should be before the starting tag of placemark id=2!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is comment by me-->
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark id="1">
      <title>something</title>
      <description>something</description>
      <LookAt>
        <Longitude>49.69</Longitude>
        <Latitude>32.345</Latitude>
      </LookAt>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>49.69,32.345,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
      <Placemark id="1">
        <title>something</title>
        <description>something</description>
        <LookAt>
          <Longitude>49.69</Longitude>
          <Latitude>32.345</Latitude>
        </LookAt>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>49.69,32.345,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is each time you recurse, you are adding the element to the newly created item. It seems that a loop would work better.

Essentially code is doing this:

set up the kml outbody
1st call and add element (element 1) to kml outerboy
2nd call add element (element 2) to (element 1)
3rd call add element (element 3) to (element 2).

If you wanted to do a recursive method rather then the looping mechanism, pass in a reference to the outer kml .

The recursive is more confusing if this is exactly how it works

(Sorry if I have an extra or missing parenthesis, comma, or other item. I don't have VS installed on this)

Looping:

```
private void xmlBuild()
{
    XElement documentElement = new XElement(ns + "Document");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        documentElement.Add(rec_build());
    }

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
        new XComment("This is comment by me"),
        new XElement(ns + "kml", documentElement));

    doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\markers2.xml"));
}

private XElement rec_build()
{

    return new XElement(ns + "Placemark",
           new XAttribute("id", "1"),
           new XElement(ns + "title", "something"),
           new XElement(ns + "description", "something"),
           new XElement(ns + "LookAt",
           new XElement(ns + "Longitude", "49.69"),
           new XElement(ns + "Latitude", "32.345")), 
           new XElement(ns + "Point", 
           new XElement(ns + "coordinates", "49.69,32.345,0")));
}
```

Recursive:

```
private void xmlBuild()
{
    XElement docElement = new XElement(ns+"Document");
    rec_build(docElement);
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
    new XComment("This is comment by me"),
    new XElement(ns+"kml", docElement)));      
    doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\markers2.xml"));
}
private XElement rec_build(XElement doc)
{
    if (iteration != 0)
    {
        iteration -= 1;
        doc.Add(new XElement(ns + "Placemark",
                new XAttribute("id", "1"),
                new XElement(ns + "title", "something"),
                new XElement(ns + "description", "something"),
                new XElement(ns + "LookAt",
                new XElement(ns + "Longitude", "49.69"),
                new XElement(ns + "Latitude", "32.345")), 
                new XElement(ns + "Point", new XElement(ns + "coordinates", "49.69,32.345,0")));
        return recBuild(doc);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I first tried to do it with a FOR loop, but got more confused so I came up with the idea of using recursion. What do you suggest for using a loop?

Comment: I went for your suggestion (calling the rec_function outer kml), but did not get good results. what else do you suggest?

Comment: @AminM updated my response. It should work. I just ran it through my head (no ide).

Comment: The looping version has problem, BUT the recursive function works perfect! Thank you! and up-top for this recursive function!!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the recursively build elements as children of Placemark and not Document. This should do the trick:

```
    private void xmlBuild()
    {
        XElement docElement = new XElement(ns + "Document");
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
                new XComment("This is comment by me"),
                new XElement(ns + "kml", docElement));
        rec_build(docElement);
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\markers2.xml"));
    }

    private XElement rec_build(XElement docElement)
    {
        if (iteration != 0)
        {
            iteration -= 1;
            return final_rec = new XElement(ns + "Placemark",
                    new XAttribute("id", "1"),
                    new XElement(ns + "title", "something"),
                    new XElement(ns + "description", "something"),
                    new XElement(ns + "LookAt",
                    new XElement(ns + "Longitude", "49.69"),
                    new XElement(ns + "Latitude", "32.345")), 
                    new XElement(ns + "Point", new XElement(ns + "coordinates", "49.69,32.345,0")));
            docElement.Add(final_rec);
            rec_build(docElement);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, this is what I get as output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This is comment by me-->
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Document />
</kml>

Comment: i had a small typo in the docElement.Add(final_rec); call, havent run this code, but it should work when fixing the typo